# Ion-select not selecting multiple values from ng-model

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am currently working with ionic 3. I have a select that accepts multiple entries.
However, at the lunching of the page i am checking for already existing selected value and pushing them into an array. finally i am assigning this array as[(ngModel)] to the select. 
THE PROBLEM is that the selected item do not show unless i press on the select. if i do press then they show that some items were selected. how can i make them show from the beginning?

HTML Code:

```html
 <ion-select class="sel1" multiple [(ngModel)]="chosenindustries" [disabled]="editable">
              <ion-option *ngFor="let indu of industries" [value]="indu.ID">{{indu.IndustryName}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
```

knowing that industries is a preloaded array that contains objects that i populate the options based on

and i am defining the data array as follow

```html
public chosenindustries: any = [3, 4, 8, 6 ,5];
```

Answer (score 0):

please replace this code may it well work you forgot property multiple="true"

```
 <ion-select class="sel1" multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="chosenindustries" [disabled]="editable">
              <ion-option *ngFor="let indu of industries" [value]="indu.ID">{{indu.IndustryName}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
```

if you want something display in starting you can use placeholder e.g

```
placeholder="Start Time"
```

Comment: multiple and multiple="true" are the same. and usually it displays the data selected but in my case it doesnt display them until i press the select. and a place holder doesnt fix my issue. thanks for your attempt sir.

Comment: @AliYsf can you share industries array that you pass on *ngFor loop ?

Comment: an example:[
{
ID: 465,
IndustryName: "Accommodation",
FamilyID: 0,
FamilyName: null,
ISICode: "55",
FamilyISICode: null
},
{
ID: 542,
IndustryName: "Activities auxiliary to financial service and insurance activities",
FamilyID: 0,
FamilyName: null,
ISICode: "66",
FamilyISICode: null
},
{
ID: 547,
IndustryName: "Activities auxiliary to insurance and pension funding",
FamilyID: 0,
FamilyName: null,
ISICode: "662",
FamilyISICode: null
}]

Comment: please add click event e.g (click)="itemClick(chosenindustries)" on ion-select create that method on ts file once your array complete call this function i hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution.

I have create demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ion-select-not-selecting-multiple-values-from-ng-model?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

```
<ion-select class="sel1" multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="chosenindustries" [disabled]="editable">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let indu of industries" [value]="indu">{{indu.IndustryName}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>


    <div>{{chosenindustries | json }}</div>
```

Comment: That is a partial way to make things better but it is not addressing the main problem.